# SQL Server - Deadlock during two concurrent DELETE

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I've got a Java app exposing a REST API to delete records in a table (SQL Server), sometimes the API must handle concurrent deletion requests (each request uses a different DB session)

Here is an extract of the DB schema:

```
MailingInstruction
------------------
id (PK)
[...]
addressId (FK to Address table)

Address
------------------
id (PK)
street
street_nr
[...]
```

The deletion of a MailingInstruction record triggers a cascade deletion of the associated Address. Each MailingInstruction has a dedicated Address (no re-use)

But from time to time, one of the concurrent delete fails because of a deadlock:

> Transaction (Process ID 51) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

So I enabled some logs:

```
DBCC TRACEON(1222, 3605,-1)
```

And it seems the problem is a DELETE on Address record which is strange because as I delete by primary key I thought the lock would be only on the specific record.

Here is the deadlock trace:

> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.39 spid15s     deadlock-list
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.39 spid15s      deadlock victim=process80ba33848
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.40 spid15s       process-list
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.40 spid15s        process id=process80ba33848 taskpriority=0 logused=348 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594043564032 (e82f06e0affb) waittime=1424 ownerId=30578 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=> 2021-09-17T09:53:51.967 XDES=0x113be80420 lockMode=S schedulerid=4 kpid=684 status=suspended spid=51 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=> 2021-09-17T09:53:51.970 lastbatchcompleted=> 2021-09-17T09:53:51.967 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.967 clientapp=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server hostname=MY-DESKTOP hostpid=0 loginname=sa isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=30578 currentdb=5 currentdbname=MY_DB lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128058
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.44 spid15s         executionStack
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.45 spid15s          frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=24 stmtend=100 sqlhandle=0x02000000627bbe0c9854b43c4ee3d7183c254e990331f4e80000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.46 spid15s     unknown
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.46 spid15s          frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.47 spid15s     unknown
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.47 spid15s         inputbuf
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.47 spid15s     (@P0 bigint)delete from Address where addressId=@P0
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.48 spid15s        process id=process80ba1f088 taskpriority=0 logused=352 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594043564032 (036d9ed30da4) waittime=1424 ownerId=30579 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=> 2021-09-17T09:53:51.967 XDES=0x1137680420 lockMode=S schedulerid=2 kpid=604 status=suspended spid=53 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=> 2021-09-17T09:53:51.970 lastbatchcompleted=> 2021-09-17T09:53:51.967 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.967 clientapp=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server hostname=MY-DESKTOP hostpid=0 loginname=sa isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=30579 currentdb=5 currentdbname=MY_DB lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128058
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.51 spid15s         executionStack
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.52 spid15s          frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=24 stmtend=100 sqlhandle=0x02000000627bbe0c9854b43c4ee3d7183c254e990331f4e80000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.53 spid15s     unknown
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.53 spid15s          frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.54 spid15s     unknown
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.54 spid15s         inputbuf
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.54 spid15s     (@P0 bigint)delete from Address where addressId=@P0
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.55 spid15s       resource-list
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.55 spid15s        keylock hobtid=72057594043564032 dbid=5 objectname=MY_DB.dbo.MailingInstruction indexname=PK__MailingI__F3FD20CC83FED272 id=lock1146070b80 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594043564032
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.56 spid15s         owner-list
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.56 spid15s          owner id=process80ba1f088 mode=X
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.57 spid15s         waiter-list
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.57 spid15s          waiter id=process80ba33848 mode=S requestType=wait
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.57 spid15s        keylock hobtid=72057594043564032 dbid=5 objectname=MY_DB.dbo.MailingInstruction indexname=PK__MailingI__F3FD20CC83FED272 id=lock11393baa00 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594043564032
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.58 spid15s         owner-list
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.59 spid15s          owner id=process80ba33848 mode=X
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.59 spid15s         waiter-list
> 2021-09-17 09:53:53.59 spid15s          waiter id=process80ba1f088 mode=S requestType=wait

Any idea why the deletion of two different records triggers this deadlock ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And it seems the problem is a DELETE on Address record which is strange because as I delete by primary key I thought the lock would be only on the specific record.

Sure, on Address. But then it scans MailingInstruction to implement the cascade delete.

The leading cause of deadlocks on [cascade delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/conor-vs-isolation-level-upgrade-on-updatedelete-cascading-ri) is not having proper indexing on your Foreign Keys.  AddressID must *at a minimum* have an index, and preferably it's the leading column of the Primary Key of MailingInstruction.

Answer (score 3):

### Lead Docks

One problem you may be running into is around [implicit transactions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/implicit-transactions-why-unrelated-queries-block-each-other/), which are the default for the JDBC driver. You can verify this in the deadlock details you posted: `transactionname=implicit_transaction`.

You can change this by using `con.setAutoCommit(true);` in your connection string.

### Somewhat Interesting

A point of interest is that the lock mode for this delete is shared: `lockMode=S`. That may indicate there's a [lookup involved in the query plan](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/lookups-deadlocks-and-you/).

You can get the plan for the delete by running this query, as long as it's still in the plan cache.

```
SELECT
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_worker_time,
text = 
    SUBSTRING
    (
        st.text, 
        ( qs.statement_start_offset / 2 ) + 1,
        (
          ( 
            CASE qs.statement_end_offset 
                 WHEN -1 
                 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text) 
                 ELSE qs.statement_end_offset 
            END - qs.statement_start_offset 
          ) / 2 
        ) + 1
    ),
    query_plan =
        TRY_CAST(qp.query_plan AS xml)
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text
(
    qs.sql_handle
) AS st  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan 
(
    qs.plan_handle,
    qs.statement_start_offset,
    qs.statement_end_offset
) AS qp
WHERE qs.sql_handle = 0x02000000E1E2A73A5B449F98DAE6C300BE7E0DBC30E139D00000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
```

It could also indicate that there are other queries in the batch along with the delete that aren't showing up in the deadlock graph, because deadlock graphs are hot garbage.

### Generality

If you're going to continue using implicit transactions, it would behoove you to turn on [Read Committed Snapshot Isolation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation) to avoid other complications with the absurd locking that takes place under the [Read Committed](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level) isolation level, which is also hot garbage.

You can turn that on like so, just sub in your database name:

```
ALTER DATABASE 
    StackOverflow 
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON 
    WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```